# How two azure web apis communicate in azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps, azure-app-api

We have two azure web apis, **app 1** and **app 2**.

We get request to **app1** after doing some business logic we need to call **app2** and get back the request to **app1** and send the request to client of **app1**.

- Is there a way to communicate with **app2** from **app1** using *IAM* or using *AAD*?

Comment: Is it possible using the portal no code. I know that we can use the ADAL libraries but is there a way in portal using IAM or any settings to give access to apps to inter communicate

Comment: Is this an [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) or say an [ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet-framework) or something else?

Comment: It’s an web api

Comment: The approach which you specified needs code in all the services.

Comment: Otherwise what do you want? Just a setting? This is the only way using AAD, also IAM is not possible.

Comment: Yeah something like IAM or managed service to communicate between apps

Comment: That's not possible. Azure RBAC is used to manage azure resources, not for your case.

Comment: I think we can use managed identities and communicate without using obo

Comment: If you add the MSI of web app1 to app2, the MSI of app1 can do something like restart the app2, change the app settings, etc. But this is in the management tier, not used to call the api. For the two apps regisered in AAD, you could just use the OBO flow.

Comment: Is there a way to use MSI like app service or azure function getting tokens for Azure Key Vault to access?

Comment: I'm using the OBO https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof-ca. But we don't have access to create control access due to organization restrictions. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Azure AD [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

The OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

[image]